# Mapping multi-level class inheritance hierarchies in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy, hierarchy

## Background

I have an existing database with 3 levels of dependent tables. Here I give an example of a 3-level, joined table, inheritance mapping problem I cannot solve. Unfortunately I cannot change the database design.

## Problem

If I execute:

```
entities = session.query(Entity)
for ent in entities:
    print ent.isin
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Asset' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

However the following code executes fine:

```
entities = session.query(Entity)
for ent in entities:
    print ent.composition
```

## Question

So the attribute `composition` is accessible but **not** `isin` !?!?

It seems obvious that the classes `Entity` and `Asset` are being mapped, **but not** `Listed`. Why would this be so?

I would have believed that sqlalchemy would be able to map to an arbitrary depth of inheritance.

I have read the docs, tried everything and I am stumped. Please help.

## Inheritance mapping

```
class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    entity_type = Column('type',String)
    source_table_id = Column(Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'entity',
        'polymorphic_on':entity_type,
        }


class Asset(Entity):    
    __tablename__ = 'asset'

    id = Column('entity_id',Integer, ForeignKey('entity.id'), primary_key=True)
    asset_type = Column('type',String)
    asset_class = Column('class',String)
    composition = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'asset',
        'polymorphic_on':asset_type,
        }


class Listed(Asset):
    __tablename__ = 'listed'

    id = Column('asset_entity_id',Integer, ForeignKey('asset.entity_id'), primary_key=True)
    ticker = Column(String)
    isin = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'listed',
        }
```

Comment: you appear to be missing `polymorphic_on` from the mapper args for the `Listed` class.

Comment: @justin-solms: you are asking the same question three times during one month already, and it looks like no one can help you with this case. If you really need it so badly, I recommend you get in touch with [Mike Bayer](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/), the creator of `sqlalchemy` for advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe this is just a coincidence with your data.

You should be either iterating over the particular type of object you want to look at e.g.

```
entities = session.query(Asset)
for ent in entities:
    print ent.composition
```

and

```
entities = session.query(Listed)
for ent in entities:
    print ent.isin
```

or checking the type of object before you access an attribute on that type of object

```
entities = session.query(Entity)
for ent in entities:
    if isinstance(ent, Asset):
        print ent.composition
    else isinstance(ent, Listing):
        print ent.isin
```

Otherwise what's going to happen is you're going to get an Entity object which will be either a `Listing` or a `Asset` object. If you hardcode the attribute `isin` then it's going to break when dealing with an `Asset` object because the `Asset` object does not have an `isin` property.